# What is the maximum training dataset size in stanford nlp sentiment tool

Tags: stanford-nlp

While training a PTB format dataset for stanford nlp sentiment tool, I got a message like:

```
Epoch:207 Batch:404
Training time :86400311ms
Max training time exceeded,exiting.
```

It is not training the entire dataset and exiting in the middle of training.

Please tell me what is the maximum training dataset size for stanford sentiment tool. Also, I would like to know the minimum RAM requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the maximum training time for the model with the command-line option:

```
-maxTrainTimeSeconds <time>
```

The time and memory requirements depend on the size of the training data; if you got as far as you did in training, the memory you are using is likely ok. There's no maximum dataset size.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But how would I come to know how much time is required to train the dataset. If the dataset is very large, is there any method to find the max training time? Does it depend on the RAM size?

Comment: Also, does the training time varies with RAM size?

Comment: The sentiment training will run for as long as you want it to—it's up to you to choose a maximum training time. Training time required depends on CPU/RAM specs, corpus size, average sentence length, etc. etc. To be safe, you can just set the maximum time to a very high number; watch the development scores and once it seems to have converged, cut things off manually. (You can have the training program save intermediate models to make this possible.)